# how to coding nest tags in language slim

Tags: ruby, slim-lang

I would like to write below in language slim.

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

and

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

I can embed it by inline HTML, so just interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
```

SLIM:

```
li.active
  a href="#" 
    | Link
    span.sr-only (current)
```

and for this HTML code:

```
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

you can write slim:

```
a.dropdown-toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" 
  | Dropdown
  span.caret
```

For your reference:

- HTML2SLIM : https://html2slim.herokuapp.com/
- SLIM2HTML : http://slim2html.raving.systems/

Comment: Thank you very much and I was surprised you could predict my another line!

Comment: This is incorrect, however. `| Link` will not leave the space between "Link" and the following span, and `span.sr-only (current)` will create an attribute "current" rather than text "(current)" (due to parentheses), yielding HTML that is quite different from the one in OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
li.active
  a href="#"
    ' Link
    span.sr-only
      | (current)

a.dropdown-toggle href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
  ' Dropdown
  span.caret
```